# Using the word "hot" as "beautiful/attractive"?

Tags: traducción

How can I use the word "Hot" as "Beautiful/attractive" in Spanish?

To translate:

> She is a hot girl

I am thinking on using:

> Ella esta una bonita chica
>
> Ella es tan caliente

Do the above sentences make sense in Spanish?

Comment: You might want to check the difference between *ser/estar* as well. Your first sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: N.B (I haven't any references) but, if someone says _chica caliente_ `hot girl` will be understood as refering to _horny girl_ focusing mostly in her/his sexual attractiveness, but `beautiful` is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Ella esta una bonita chica
>
> Do the above sentences make sense in spanish?

The above phrase doesn't make sense because it's a literal translation of the verb **to be**. One of the main differences between English and Spanish, and one of the most common mistakes English speakers make when learning.

> - Ella es tan Caliente

Also, I agree with @Paco in that '*caliente*' can mean horny in many places. But, you can use '*bonita*' or '*bonito*' when referring to people too. It is specially common when referring to babies or girls, for example. It relates with an attractive cuteness, as opposed to sexy.

So, when meaning hot, you can use the word '*sexy*'. One of many [anglicisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicism#Anglicisms_in_Spanish) Spanish language uses.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *estar caliente* means "to be horny", so careful. In Spain we say *estar bueno* (which is different from *ser bueno* "to be good"). The adjective *bonito* is not normally used for people, only for animals or objects.

Also remember that most of the times, the adjective goes after the noun.

Comment: In Chile there's no problem with saying that a person is _bonito/a_. "Mi esposa es bonita" is OK.

Comment: Same in Colombia, we can say that a girl is *bonita* if we'd like to point out that she's pretty. If we'd like to point out a stronger desire *estar buena* is just fine.

Comment: Bonita/o can be used with people, maybe is not common in some countries, but even the movie "Pretty Woman" was translated to "Mujer bonita". Y esta buena/o tambien depende del pais.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a better translation of `hot` is `sensual`.
`Hot` refers to sexual attractiveness and not simply to beauty (in the traditional way).
So for `She is hot`, you could say:

```
Ella es (muy) sensual
```

`Beautiful` is translated as `Hermosa/o`. Traditionally `Bonito/a` is not as attractive/graced as `Beautiful/Hermosa`.

`Bonito/a` is a very good translation for `Pretty`. When you say `pretty`, you refer to certain cuteness/attractiveness that does not necessarily match perfectly with the traditional `beautiful`.

`Beautiful` refers more to the correction/perfection of the features. Of course, someone `Beautiful` can also be considered `Hot`, but when you use one word or the other you are highlighting different things.

Also if when you say `hot` you want to highlight that the person you are talking about has, lets say "big curves", you can use "voluptuosa", as in:

> Es una mujer (muy)voluptuosa

Finally, I want to clarify that words such as `Beautiful/Hermosa`, `Pretty/Bonita`, are usually used interchangeably. I mean, when you call your girlfriend `Pretty/Bonita`, is not as you are thinking "*you are just pretty not beautiful*".

Comment: I like this one. In Spain I think "beautiful" could be translated as "guapa" or "preciosa", being "preciosa" better than "guapa"

Answer (score 3):

As always, the phrase "She is a hot girl" can be translated in different ways depending of the area. Where I come from (Puerto Rico), this is the formal way we use:

> ¡Ella es muy bonita / hermosa / preciosa!

If you are talking with friends, for example, you may hear these other variations:

> ¡Ella está bien buena!
>
> ¡Ella está bien dura!

or using a simile:

> ¡Ella está mas dura que las tablas de multiplicar!

**Please note that using the last three phrases (especially the last two) may be considered pejorative for some people.**

Comment: I am from Puerto Rico. I added this to the answer.